# Unable to find compiled c++ library function

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I have a file called ***libmylibrary.a*** and a header file called ***mylibrary.h***   *this contains a function called myfunction()*. I combined them with a cpp file (***HelloWorldJNI.cpp***) to make a new library named ***native.dll***. However, when I try to compile ***native.dll*** in Java using JNI, I can't locate the functions from libmylibrary.a and mylibrary.h.

**mylibrary.h**

```
// mylibrary.h
#ifndef MYLIBRARY_H
#define MYLIBRARY_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void myFunction();  // Declare the function prototype

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // MYLIBRARY_H
```

These are the steps i followed
1. Created java file for integrating JNI (HelloWorldJNI.java)

```
public class HelloWorldJNI {
    static {
        System.load("/home/centos/test5/native.dll");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorldJNI().sayHello();
    }
  //native method with no body
  public native void sayHello();
}
```

2. created HelloWorldJNI.h file using this command

```
javac -h .  HelloWorldJNI.java
```

3.integrated mylibrary.h file and HelloWorldJNI.h file with my cpp file (HelloWorldJNI.cpp)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<jni.h>
#include "mylibrary.h"
#include "HelloWorldJNI.h"
void sayHello(){
  myFunction();
}
int main() {
    sayHello();  // Call the function from the library

    return 0;
}
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorldJNI_sayHello
  (JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObject) {
    sayHello();
}
```

4.  Compiled these files (created .o file)

```
g++ HelloWorldJNI.cpp -L. -lmylibrary -I"/home/centos/jdk-21.0.1/include" -I"/home/centos/jdk-21.0.1/include/linux" -o HelloWorldJNI.o
```

5.  Generated .o file to .dll file

```
g++ -shared -o native.dll HelloWorldJNI.o
```

6. Compiled and run HelloWorldJNI.java

```
java HelloWorldJNI
```

Getting this error:

```
java: symbol lookup error: /home/centos/test5/native.dll: undefined symbol: myFunction
```

How do I incorporate **libmylibrary.a** into my Java code compilation to ensure that it recognizes the functions in **libmylibrary.a**?

PS: I am sure there is no issue with libmylibrary.a because i was able to call myFunction() using pure c++ but while using JNI there seems to be some kind of linking issue which i am not able to figure out

Comment: The `-l` and `-L` flags do nothing when compiling to a .o file. Use them when you generate the shared library instead. Better still, forego the object file and just compile your cpp file to a library directly.

Comment: @Botje tried this as well in step 5 not working
**-g++ -shared -L. -lmylibrary  -I"/home/centos/jdk-21.0.1/include" -I"/home/centos/jdk-21.0.1/include/linux" -o native.dll HelloWorldJNI.o**

Comment: The `-l` arguments need to go at the end of the line. More specifically after the .o files that need them. Also note that the file name should be `libnative.so` on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all your steps with the minor changes and that works for me. Attaching the build script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

JAVA_SDK_HOME=/home/user/lib/jdk-21.0.1

#echo BUILD THE LIB
#g++ -c mylibrary.cpp -o mylibrary.o
#ar rcs libmylibrary.a mylibrary.o

echo MAKE JAVA STUB
$JAVA_SDK_HOME/bin/javac -h . HelloWorldJNI.java

echo BUILD SO file
g++ -c -fPIC -o HelloWorldJNI.o HelloWorldJNI.cpp \
  -I $JAVA_SDK_HOME/include/ \
  -I $JAVA_SDK_HOME/include/linux

g++ -shared -o native.dll HelloWorldJNI.o -L. -lmylibrary

echo TESTING
$JAVA_SDK_HOME/bin/java HelloWorldJNI
```

The are a few notes though:

1. On Windows most probably you have to set some macros so `JNIEXPORT` is actually `__declspec(dllexport)`, not `__declspec(dllimport)`
2. To link the `*.so` file on Linux you need C++ files to be compiled with `-fPIC`

Comment: I don't have **mylibrary.cpp**  I only have compiled version of this, i.e mylibrary.a and its header file i.e **mylibrary.h**, and i am compiling it on the Linux system

Comment: @RooheinMalhotra At step 4 looks like you are missing `-c` so `HelloWorldJNI.o` is actually an executable rather than obj file

Comment: Weird, yesterday when I compiled the SO file I got a message about symbols reallocation, so I had to add `-fPIC`. Today I'm able to compile without `-fPIC`

Comment: yes, please try using this command  
g++ -c -fPIC -L. -lmylibrary -I"/home/centos/jdk-21.0.1/include" -I"/home/centos/jdk-21.0.1/include/linux" HelloWorldJNI.cpp

this will create .o file rather than .exe file

Comment: @RooheinMalhotra `-l` and `-L` are not needed when you build with `-c`. I've updated the script above. Please try. Does it work for your?

Comment: @RooheinMalhotra "I don't have mylibrary.cpp I only have compiled version of this, i.e mylibrary.a and its header file i.e mylibrary.h" - That's a bad situation to be in. Ususally you want to compile *everything* that is part of your application with the *same compiler* and the same optimization flags. You cannot (in general) assume that objects compiled with different compilers (or different options) will be binary compatible.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It is ok as long as it is C API and the data layout does not depend on compilation flags (packing, marcos, etc).

Comment: I disagree. But you are welcome to do the same.

Comment: BTW @RooheinMalhotra Java is a platform neutral framework. When you load DLL, you should take care of CPU architecture.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Can you provide an example when properly designed C API suffer from the compiler dependencies ? Assuming the library is provided as a shared object (DLL). When I've been working on C# -> C++ adapter, I mixed DLLs compiled with MSVC, GCC, CLANG. It worked just great.